# Why is there a constant stutter when i move in Unity 2d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, game-development

So i have a simple scene in unity, a player with a parallax background and a Tilemap as a ground, as well as some very simple post processing. I know this isn't a  The minute i move, there is a consistent stutter just under ever second. I'm not sure whether it's to do with my player movement code, camera movement or anything else. I'm also using a Cinemachine virtual camera. My rigidbody interpolation is set to interpolate and collision detection set to continuous. Here's my player movement if this helps. Here is a sample of what it looks like, if you look at the background or the tilemap it's quite noticeable. https://youtu.be/h2rSheZWtKs

```
[SerializeField] private LayerMask groundLayerMask;
public float speed;
public float Jump;
public sword swordScript;
public GameObject swordSprite;
private float move;
private Rigidbody2D rb;
private BoxCollider2D boxCollider2d;
private bool facingRight;
public SpriteRenderer spr;
public Animator PlayerAnims;
public bool movementAllowed;

void Awake()
{
    Application.targetFrameRate = 60;
    Application.targetFrameRate = Screen.currentResolution.refreshRate;
    boxCollider2d = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    facingRight = true;
    spr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
}
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    boxCollider2d = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    facingRight = true;
    spr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
}



// Update is called once per frame

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if(movementAllowed == true)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(move * speed, rb.velocity.y);

        if (isGrounded() && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, Jump));
        }
    }
}


void Update()
{

    move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(move * speed, rb.velocity.y);

    if (movementAllowed == true)
    {
        Flip(move);

        if (move == 0)
        {
            PlayerAnims.SetBool("isRunning", false);
        }
        else
        {
            PlayerAnims.SetBool("isRunning", true);
        }
    }
}


private bool isGrounded()
{
    float extraHeightText = .1f;
    RaycastHit2D raycasthit2d = Physics2D.BoxCast(boxCollider2d.bounds.center, boxCollider2d.bounds.size, 0f, Vector2.down,  extraHeightText, groundLayerMask);
    Color rayColour;
    if (raycasthit2d.collider != null)
    {
        rayColour = Color.green;
        PlayerAnims.SetBool("isJumping", false);
    }
    else
    {
        rayColour = Color.red;
        PlayerAnims.SetBool("isJumping", true);

    }
    Debug.DrawRay(boxCollider2d.bounds.center + new Vector3(boxCollider2d.bounds.extents.x, 0), Vector2.down * (boxCollider2d.bounds.extents.y + extraHeightText), rayColour);
    Debug.DrawRay(boxCollider2d.bounds.center - new Vector3(boxCollider2d.bounds.extents.x, 0), Vector2.down * (boxCollider2d.bounds.extents.y + extraHeightText), rayColour);
    Debug.DrawRay(boxCollider2d.bounds.center - new Vector3(boxCollider2d.bounds.extents.x, boxCollider2d.bounds.extents.y + extraHeightText), Vector2.right * (boxCollider2d.bounds.extents.x), rayColour);

    return raycasthit2d.collider != null;
}
private void Flip(float move)
{
    if (move > 0 && !facingRight || move < 0 && facingRight)
    {
        facingRight = !facingRight;

        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;

        theScale.x *= -1;

        transform.localScale = theScale;

        if (swordScript.isFollowing == true)
        {
            Vector3 swordScale = swordSprite.transform.localScale;

            swordScale.x *= -1;

            swordSprite.transform.localScale = swordScale;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `rb.velocity` in both the `Update()` and `FixedUpdate()` methods.  I would try only using one of those.

On top of that, your jump check also re-applies the X velocity along with the upward force.  So if you're jumping the player will be pushed forward at double speed.

You also have an error being outputted in the console about an Index being out of range... I would look into that.

Can you also post your code for the parallax background?

Comment: After disabling the parallax script, it seems the issue hasn't changed whatsoever, so im not sure that that is the problem @John Also, i tried just setting rb.velocity just once in both update methods and that didn't change the issue either! Thank you for pointing that out though :)

Comment: @bblakeyyy Have you tried continuing down that path of disabling things?  Maybe use a regular camera, and disable all the post processing for now?

Comment: @bblakeyyy you could also take a look at the profiler and see if something if the stutters are known to Unity, which I would assume they would be.  Basically just open the Profiler window (Window -> Analysis -> Profiler) and run the game.  It should show you spikes when the stutters occur, and then you can pause the game and click on the chart to see what is slowing things down.

Comment: I have yeah, i've tried disabling every single thing in the scene and it persists. I am at a loss. I did try the profiler earlier but i'm gonna give it another go now.

Answer (score 0):

`FixedUpdate` is a method where you want to do **everything physics, player-controller and simulation related**.
`Update` is just for rendering-related fluff i.e. code of no real consequence other than making things look correctly.

Hence:

1. Move all your player/physics controller code to FixedUpdate.
2. Move bg parallax code to Update.
3. Use Time.deltaTime (in Update) and Time.fixedDeltaTime (in FixedUpdate) time steps when animating or interpolating between values.

---

Ad #3.: Although - as [@Menyus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11124332/menyus) noted (below) - Time.deltaTime is all you really need.

Time.fixedDeltaTime is for that extra intent explicitness (but was necessary in earlier unity versions).

Comment: Actually if you use time.deltaTime in a `FixedUpdate` it will return the correct time, thus using `time.deltaTime` in a `FixedUpdate` is the Unity recommended way
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html

Comment: It's just a kids-friendly safety mechanism. But seasoned devs must know what is what and why.

Comment: I don't mean it acrimoniously. This issue is an old one, laborous to communicate and was comming up daily.

Comment: I see, i just added side notes to your answer that using `time.fixedDeltaTime` is unnecessary, and using `time.deltaTime` inside a `FixedUpdate()` should be no source of bugs